# Refilling fields with value under fields_for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with fields such as a drop down and text fields. Upon submitting the form and returning some errors, the fields that I have defined under the fields_for are not populated. How do I retain the values, that the user chose before he submitted the form, on the fields_for?

Here's my views codes:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'FIRSTNAME' %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: "input-text personal", placeholder: 'LASTNAME' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :doctor do |p| %>
        <%= p.collection_select(:specialization_id, Specialization.order(:order), :id, :description, {include_blank: ''}, class: "js-specialization js-select2", id: "specialization-select", "data-placeholder" => "SPECIALIZATION")%>

        <%= p.collection_select(:institution_id, Institution.order(:order), :id, :description, {include_blank: '', selected: params[:institution_id]}, class: "js-institution js-select2", id: "institution-select", "data-placeholder" => "INSTITUTION") %>
                    <%= p.text_field :license_number, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'LICENSE NUMBER' %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Values should be retained, what browser are you using? Is javascript enabled?

Comment: Im using chrome and yup, javascripts are enabled. Values are retained outside the fields_for block upon submit.